# Add a class/table inside another one in Parse.com (android)

Tags: android, database, parse-platform

In one of my Parse.com classes/tables I'd like to have a column where another class/table can be stored for each row. As an example:

An User table with a Clothes row, in which a table with the name and color of each of the user's items can be stored.

I've done this using relations but was wondering if there's a way to do it without having to create another table and making a relation to it, since that creates two tables (the table itself and the relation). I'm just trying to make it so Parse.com has the least stress so querys or any method can be done in the least time.

Thanks, if I didn't make myself clear please ask.